# AlarmManager run

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have a AlarmManager that run at the 20:00, but also run when i click the button for fix it. I only want that run at the 20:00

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
AlarmManager a = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
a.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,p);
```

Comment: If it's past 20:00 and you set the alarm, it will be executed instantly, like the [docs say](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). Best thing you can do is compute the time difference.

Comment: How i compute the time difference?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128091/setting-up-alarm-manager-is-creating-2-instances-of-my-main-activity/16134932#16134932 its working code for 20 second repeated alarm forever.

Answer (score 1):

Put Below code in your code for repeating alarm at specific time

```
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() <= c.getTimeInMillis()){

        AlarmManager a = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        a.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,p);

    }
```

i hope it helps you...